# Why does this simple Arduino sketch slow down after a short while?

Tags: serialization, arduino, usb

I have a rather simple Arduino sketch (see below) for an Uno3, which in the main loop reads a number of sensors and serial.prints (sends) the result (as characters) to the serial port at 9600 baud.

The first 24 loops or so runs at the intended speed (variable wait), but then the speed slows down considerably -- for time stamps (millis) see below.

I assume this must have something to do with the sensor readings, as an even simpler sketch which just sends the millis() will continue at full speed. Or is it perhaps the serial comm which gets clogged up?

My simple sketch:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

const int oneWireBus = 7; 
// read the input on analog pin 0:
int vas = analogRead(A0);
int time = millis();
int wait = 10;


OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  sensors.requestTemperatures();

  if (millis() > time + wait) {
     time = time + wait; 

    //Serial.println(Serial.availableForWrite());
    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(analogRead(A5));
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(4));
    //delay(10);        // delay in between reads for stability
    if (vas > 300) {
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);  
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);  
    }
  }
}
```

...produces a serial stream like this:

```
48,171,0,22.50,1
77,172,0,22.50,1
107,172,0,22.50,1
138,171,0,22.50,1
167,172,0,22.50,1
197,171,0,22.50,1
227,171,0,22.50,1
258,170,0,22.50,1
287,170,0,22.50,1
317,171,0,22.50,1
347,171,0,22.50,1
377,172,0,22.50,1
407,171,0,22.50,1
437,172,0,22.50,1
466,170,0,22.50,1
497,171,0,22.50,1
527,170,0,22.50,1
557,171,0,22.50,1
586,171,0,22.50,1
617,171,0,22.50,1
647,170,0,22.50,1
676,171,0,22.50,1
706,171,0,22.50,1
737,171,0,22.50,1
1350,172,0,22.50,1
2023,170,0,22.50,1
2697,172,0,22.50,1
3369,170,0,22.50,1
4043,171,0,22.50,1
4716,171,0,22.50,1
```

..notice how the time for each loop is about 30ms up until time 737 and then it increases to about 700ms

If I run this little sketch:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(millis());
}
```

..each loop takes about 4ms to 10ms and continues to do so ...

I have tried Serial.flush() in each loop and also to only read sensors when Serial.availableForWrite() > 30 .. no different

Any suggestions what is causing this slow down?

Comment: `Serial.flush()` won't make is send faster. It just blocks until everything is sent. If you wan't faster serial, increase the baud rate.

Comment: And the DallasTemperature library waits for conversion by default. Why are you calling `sensors.requestTemperatures()` on every loop? And then attempting to get the temperature every 10 ms, which is way too low conversion time.

Comment: int time = millis();    What's the largest value an in can hold.  I'll wait while you look it up.  I'm guessing that it runs ok for a little more than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is it perhaps the serial comm which gets clogged up?
>
> ...
>
> ..notice how the time for each loop is about 30ms up until time 737 and then it increases to about 700ms
>
> ...
>
> Any suggestions what is causing this slow down?

The Dallas Temperature sensors you are using take **up to** 750ms for the ADC to latch the temperature value in the default 12-bit resolution. When the sensors are ready they signal the response back to the bus master (the Arduino) using the 1-Wire protocol.

You can see the delays in your timings. In the first 737ms the library is ready with a reading. After this, it is blocking and waiting for the sensor to send a reading.

You can use `setWaitForConversion(FALSE)` to get a more constant delay. From https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library/blob/master/DallasTemperature.cpp#L359:

```
// sets the value of the waitForConversion flag
// TRUE : function requestTemperature() etc returns when conversion is ready
// FALSE: function requestTemperature() etc returns immediately (USE WITH CARE!!)
//        (1) programmer has to check if the needed delay has passed
//        (2) but the application can do meaningful things in that time
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timing code is wrong and susceptible to rollover errors.  You have to write it the other way around, calculate the interval and not the time in the future.

if (millis() > time + wait) {
     time = time + wait;

should be

if (millis() - time > wait) {
     time = time + wait;

This issue wouldn't ordinarily bite you so soon but you also have a variable type problem with the time variable that I pointed out in comment on your question.  Here it is again:

```
int time = millis();
```

I'm guessing that it runs ok for a little more than 30 seconds.  Look up what types of values an int variable can hold and see if you can figure out how I know that.  Then look at the classic "Blink Without Delay" example.  They all use unsigned long for time and that's what millis() returns.

Do some reading about the "Blink Without Delay" example and you will learn why it being unsigned is important.

Comment: Thanks for pointers -- I did look at Blink without delay, and fixed accordingly -- did not help.

However, commenting out the sensors.requestTemperatures (and corresponding Serial.print) fixes the issue ... So I just need to work a little with how the temp sensor is working to get around this issue.

Comment: It should be `millis() - time > wait`

Comment: Thanks gre-gor.  Fixed the typo there.

Answer (score 0):

With the very helpful comments above from Ben T, Delta_G and gre-gor, I provide a workable solution as an answer to my own question.

For pedagogical reasons, I have extended the example to allow for differentiated time lapses between reading of various sensors. More flexibility than I need, but it could come in handy.

E.g. I want to read the button status (pressed/not pressed) as often as possible, otherwise I could miss a short button press. Therefor, I include no delays at all in the loop.

Conversely, I'm quite satisfied with a temperature reading every 5 seconds. Potentiometer and submersion-sensor readings should be more frequent however, albeit not nearly as hysterically often as button presses. I also don't need to push results out through the serial port that often either -- 10 times/sec will do fine. 50 readings/sec seems to be about the maximum that my Arduino Uno rev3 can manage -- which is more than enough for me :-)

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

const int oneWireBus = 7;         // read the temperature from digital 7
const byte potentiometerPin = A0; // read the potentiometer input on analog pin 0
const byte submersionPin = A5;    // read the submersion input on analog pin 5
const byte buttonPin = 4;         // read the button input on digital pin 4
const byte relayPin = 2;          // write the relay output to digital pin 2

unsigned long timeOfLastSerialOutput = millis();        // holds time of last serial output
const long serialOutputWait = 100;                    // how long to wait between serial outputs (ms)

unsigned long timeOfLastTemperatureInput = millis();    // holds time of last temprature input
const long temperatureInputWait = 5000;               // how long to wait between temperature reads (ms)
float temperatureInputValue = 0;                      // holds the lastest temperature reading

unsigned long timeOfLastPotentiometerInput = millis();  // holds time of last potentiometer input
const long potentiometerInputWait = 500;              // how long to wait between potentiometer reads (ms)
int potentiometerInputValue = 0;                      // hold the latest potentiometer reading (0-255)

unsigned long timeOfLastSubmersionInput = millis();     // holds time of last submersion input
const long submersionInputWait = 500;                 // how long to wait between submersion reads (ms)
int submersionInputValue = 0;                         // holds the latest submersion reading (0-255)

bool buttonInputValue = false;                        // holds the latest button reading
bool buttonPressed = false;                           // holds 1 if button has been pressed since last check

unsigned long presentTime = millis();                 // holds present time 

OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.setWaitForConversion(false);
  sensors.begin();
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // we read the time and button input as often as possible -- we dont want to miss a short button press!
  presentTime = millis();
  buttonInputValue = !digitalRead(buttonPin); // We reverse (!) because open switch=1, closed switch=0
  if (buttonInputValue) { // we must remember a (short) button press in future loops -- only reset to 0 after serial send
    buttonPressed = true;
  }

  // Time to read temperature input?
  if (presentTime - timeOfLastTemperatureInput > temperatureInputWait) {
    timeOfLastTemperatureInput = presentTime;
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    temperatureInputValue = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  }

  // Time to read potentiometer input?
  if (presentTime - timeOfLastPotentiometerInput > potentiometerInputWait) {
    timeOfLastPotentiometerInput = presentTime;
    potentiometerInputValue = analogRead(potentiometerPin);
    if (potentiometerInputValue > 300) {
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);  
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(2, LOW); 
    }
  }

  // Time to read submersion sensor input?
  if (presentTime - timeOfLastSubmersionInput > submersionInputWait) {
    timeOfLastSubmersionInput = presentTime;
    submersionInputValue = analogRead(submersionPin);
  }

  // Time to write to serial output?
  if (presentTime - timeOfLastSerialOutput > serialOutputWait) {
    timeOfLastSerialOutput = presentTime;
    Serial.print(presentTime);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(potentiometerInputValue);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(submersionInputValue);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(temperatureInputValue);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(buttonPressed);
    buttonPressed = false;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help -- hope this is helpful too...